# ZIP the fasterq-dump files in loop

Tags: ncbi, sra

I want to zip the files generated by fasterq-dump simultaneously as they are generated. The code that I tried is this.

```
cat SRR_Acc_List.txt | while read i 
do  fasterq-dump ${i} --split-spot -v --skip-technical  -e 15| gzip -k  ${i}> ${i}.gz 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried, but I believe you may add `-Z` to fasterq-dump and remove `-k ${i}` from gzip. In addition, I would recommend the following:

```sh
cat SRR_Acc_List.txt | xargs -i echo fasterq-dump {} --split-spot -Z -v --skip-technical -e 15 \| gzip > {}.gz | sh
```

It is simpler and more flexible. For example, replacing `sh` with `parallel` would allow you to download in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it worked

```
cat SRR_Acc_List.txt | while read i ; do  fasterq-dump ${i} --split-spot -v --skip-technical  -e 20 ; for j in i ; do   gzip ${i}.fastq  ; done; done
```